# How to JOIN a table on alternative (either of 1 of 2) conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Looking to do a table join on alternative conditions (here, replaced substrings of the data originally found in a particular column).  So I essentially want to join on either of 1 of 2 string types found in a particular column.  The first query I have works just fine. The second query I have below runs, but just runs and runs and runs forever.

First query:

```
select *
from (select count(hls_case.case_id), count(build_opinion.source_id) as build_case_id
      from hls_case left join
           build_opinion
           on replace(substring(build_opinion.source_id, 69, 37), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') = hls_case.case_id and
              build_opinion.build_name = 'romeo3'
     );
```

Second Query:

```
select *
from (select count(hls_case.case_id), count(build_opinion.source_id) as build_case_id
      from hls_case left join
           build_opinion
           on (replace(substring(build_opinion.source_id, 69, 37), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') = hls_case.case_id or
               replace(substring(build_opinion.source_id, 61, 29), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') = hls_case.case_id
              ) and
              build_opinion.build_name = 'romeo3'
     );
```

Comment: Can't you `UNION` the 2 queries?

Comment: Do you have any say-so over the DB design? This is bound to be a slow way to analyze data. A better table setup could probably help immensely.

Comment: @Eric yes the UNION works, thanks!  But still looking to get the counts together.  And was looking for how syntax help on how to do any type of multi-condition join using "or".

Comment: @Joe Love I can update the tables, but again, was using this example as a larger question on how to do multi-condition joins.  Thanks.

Comment: Couple of things to Consider: Putting your join condition in a function is not ideal, here you are using Replace and Substring on source_id, which is not idea. Using OR has poor performance, try using IN Clause or Union instead of OR. Finally using inner query is not good for query performance, so try not to nest your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you don't want an OR in your join, unless it's a very primitive condition.  Likewise, I'd avoid greater than / less than joins across two tables.

I wouldn't bet my life that this will yield the same results, but it doesn't appear there is any possible overlap between the two conditions, so I **think** you can do two left joins, one with each condition.

This would have, at most, a single scan of each table.

```
select
  count(hls_case.case_id),
  count(coalesce (bo1.source_id, bo2.source_id)) as build_case_id
from
  hls_case
  left join build_opinion bo1 on
     replace(substring(bo1.source_id, 69, 37), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') = 
     hls_case.case_id and
     bo1.build_name = 'romeo3'
  left join build_opinion bo2 on
     replace(substring(bo2.source_id, 61, 29), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') =
     hls_case.case_id and
     bo2.build_name = 'romeo3'
```

I am making some reasonable assumptions about your data, but it is possible there is possible there are overlaps that don't jump out at me that would result in a 1:many on each of the left joins that would break this.

Answer (score 0):

I use `UNION` instead of `OR` in join condition.

```
select count(hls_case.case_id), count(build_opinion.source_id)
from (
    select hls_case.case_id, build_opinion.source_id
    from hls_case 
    left join build_opinion on replace(substring(build_opinion.source_id, 69, 37), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') = hls_case.case_id 
        and build_opinion.build_name = 'romeo3'
    union
    select hls_case.case_id, build_opinion.source_id
    from hls_case 
    left join build_opinion on replace(substring(build_opinion.source_id, 61, 29), 'redacted_CASEMETS_', '') = hls_case.case_id
        and build_opinion.build_name = 'romeo3'
)
```